# How to use 'mode' with docker secrets mounted with files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-secrets

I am testing [Docker Secrets with long syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#long-syntax-2). Unfortunately I something seems to be wrong or I cannot reproduce ownership / mode change as in following example from documentation:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    secrets:
      - source: my_secret
        target: redis_secret
        uid: '103'
        gid: '103'
        mode: 0440
secrets:
  my_secret:
    file: ./my_secret.txt
  my_other_secret:
    external: true
```

This seems to clearly state that `my_secret` is being sourced from file and there is possibility to set `gid`, `uid` and `mode` when mounted to specific location.

I've created following test `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  test:
    image: busybox:latest
    secrets:
      - source: secret_file
        target: /root/mysecretfile
        uid: '101'
        gid: '101'
        mode: 0400
    command: ls -alh /root

secrets:
  secret_file:
    file: ./docker-compose.yml
```

But running example shows that neither uid/gid nor permission to file has changed in container.

```
$ ls -alh docker-compose.yml 
-rw-r--r-- 1 devilan devilan 275 08-24 11:42 docker-compose.yml
$ docker compose up
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container secret-test-1  Created                                                                                                                                            0.0s
Attaching to secret-test-1
secret-test-1  | total 12K    
secret-test-1  | drwx------    1 root     root        4.0K Aug 24 09:41 .
secret-test-1  | drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Aug 24 09:41 ..
secret-test-1  | -rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000         275 Aug 24 09:42 mysecretfile
```

I am using one of the latest docker versions:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.17
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.5
 Git commit:        100c70180f
 Built:             Thu Aug 18 11:20:14 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.17
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.5
  Git commit:       a89b84221c
  Built:            Thu Aug 18 11:38:13 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.6.8
  GitCommit:        9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.3
  GitCommit:        6724737f999df9ee0d8ca5c6d7b81f97adc34374
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad007797e0dcd8b7126f27bb87401d224240
```

Is this a bug or I am not understanding something from documentation properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is just a limitation for how `docker compose` implements the spec. The fields were originally added for Swarm Mode which loads the secret into the database, and pushes it to nodes in the swarm on a need to know basis. Those nodes load the file into a tmpfs file that gets mounted into the container, and in that tmpfs file, they are adjusting the permissions and ownership.

With compose, I expect that to be implemented with a bind mount since there's no swarm manager and database to store the secrets in. And with a bind mount, there's no option to change the permissions and ownership between the source and target of the bind, the Linux kernel will pass those directly through.

Comment: Yeah. Bind mount there so no uid/gid/mode changes. Docker documentation is wrong in this section.

Comment: The docs describe what settings are in the compose file, but not what tools implement which settings. And even which versions of which tools.

Comment: So are there any tools that can implement those declarations into real change in mounted file? I'll be glad if you could you point any of working ones.

Comment: Swarm Mode should use them.

Comment: Yeah, that is not a problem. The example from documentation i've pointed out clearly has been using gid/uid/mode with secret sourced from file. I thought that there is some plug-in that use bindfs features or something other out of the box. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Swarm Mode initializes the secret to the value in the file when you run `docker stack deploy -c compose.yml stack_name`. Thought I don't typically recommend that since Swarm Mode secrets are immutable and it's not clear the file is no longer referenced after creation.

Comment: That clarifies it much better. Confusion came from situation you can have docker in swarm mode and still use `docker compose up` and it almost works as expected without any warning that uid/gid/mode are discarded.